# Многопоточный сервер на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, сервер, сокеты

написал многопоточный сервер, при подключении клиента выходит исключение

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 130, in 
    (conn[i], addr) = sock.accept()
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Вот код сервера:

```
import threading
import socket

def client_function(cli_numb):
**код работы с клиентом**

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("", 75))
sock.listen(100)
conn = []
i = 0
print("Wait clients...")
while True:
  (conn[i], addr) = sock.accept()
  client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_function, args=(i,))
  client_thread.start()
  i = i + 1
  del(addr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ почему это происходит есть в ответе, предоставленным @New Python Programmist

Решение: использовать заместо *list*(а именно *[]*) *dict*:

```
conn = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в данной строке (что видно по тексту ошибки):

```
(conn[i], addr) = sock.accept()
```

Дело в том, что список `conn` совершенно пуст и запрашивать элемент с любым индексом бесполезно, т.к. это вызовет исключение, которое вы видели на экране:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "server.py", line 130, in 
(conn[i], addr) = sock.accept() 
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

А конкретно:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Не знаю как преобразовать этот код, но вот так:

```
conn = []
i = 0
conn[i]
```

Делать не рекомендуется)))

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 128, in <module>
    conn[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: "Не знаю как преобразовать этот код" - а зачем же Вы тогда отвечали?

Comment: @mr-morgan Я хотел показать ошибку, а её устранением займется уже сам автор

Answer (score 0):

```
# list
conn = []  # ['con']
while True:
  (con, addr) = sock.accept()
  conn.append(con)

# dict
conn = {}  # {'con': 'addr', }
while True:
  conn.update([sock.accept()])
```